# Validate form in popup without reloading page in Django/jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, forms

I'm attempted to create the same functionality reddit has on its login page - if you go to reddit.com and click the 'login or register' link at the top right of the page it'll load a popup box to login or register. When you click submit on in the box it'll validate server-side and return errors without closing the popup box/reloading the entire page.

I'm assuming this is somehow done in ajax, but I'm uncertain as to how to do it. I have a similar popup box on my page, but I can't get validation errors to show up as they normally do by default in Django, and I'm curious how to start tackling this problem. Should I use an ajax call with jQuery and attempt to somehow send the form to Django and retrieve the validation errors? If so, how do I go about doing that? If not, what do I do instead?

Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: I can help you with the popup that you want

Comment: Did you found a good solution for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [jquery-from](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). Your view may send you the form rendered with errors, so you just need the change the form content using $(form_div).html(received_data) or it may send you a JSON list of errors which you process manually.